# Flash CS 6 how to create a button that follows the shape of the image

Tags: flash, imagebutton, flash-cs6

Problem:

I have 3 button like :[image]

even if button is png and make that shape
flash still recognize it like rectangular so
if the problem just like the picture the second button just have little hit area and some area covered by 1st button and 3rd button

how to make a button that follows the image shape?

Comment: make a shape mask on the button.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I will looking for the tutorial? Or maybe you have some tutorial link? @LDMS